# Metrizable compact space not homeomorphic to any compact in finiete dimensional space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm wondering if there's metrizable compact space $X$ such that $X$ is not homeomorphic to any compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

I know that there exists metric compact space $X$(e.g. Hilbert Cube) such that $X$ is not isometric to any compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but the condition of isometricity is essential in those case.

Comment: Why is the Hilber Cube no example? It is homeomorphic to $[0,1]^\omega$ which does not fit into any $\Bbb R^n$, does it?

Comment: You mean it’s a contradiction because of cardinality?

Comment: Yes, the Hilbert Cube is literally too big to fit into any finite-dimensional space

Comment: Okay thank you! Got it

Comment: It does not embed, but the proof requires some highly non-trivial results.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen . Cardinality is not the issue. The cardinal of any compact metric space is at most the cardinal of $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

The hilbert cube is strongly infinite-dimensional, so it's not a subspace (isometric or not) of any finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But any $n$-dimensional separable metric space can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ (Menger's universal spaces, or Nöbeling's). So infinite-dimensionality is the obstruction against embeddings into spaces $\Bbb R^N$.